# What is Causing this Lambda to Throw an Error with aws-sdk Version 3?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I have an AWS lambda function triggered by an SNS queue, which is supposed to extract some data from the message it receives, format it, then send it to a different SNS queue.  Everything was working well until I tried sending to the second queue.  In order to do so, I installed `@aws-sdk/client-sns`, and attempted to send a simple message.  When I run the code, it's throwing the following error related to not being able to find TypeScript definitions:

```sh
✖ in ./node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es/index.js 1:0-22
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './SNS' in '/Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es'
    resolve './SNS' in '/Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es'
      using description file: /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/package.json (relative path: ./dist-es)
        using description file: /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/package.json (relative path: ./dist-es/SNS)
          no extension
            /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es/SNS doesn't exist
          .ts
            /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es/SNS.ts doesn't exist
          tsx
            /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es/SNStsx doesn't exist
          as directory
            /Users/userName/development/aws-sdk-error/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es/SNS doesn't exist
```

This is the simplified version of the file throwing the error:

```js
import { SNSClient, PublishCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-sns';

export const showError = async () => {

  const client = new SNSClient( { region: 'us-west-1' } );

  const params = {
    Message: 'some text',
    TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:111111111111:someOtherTopic'
  };

  try {
    await client.send( new PublishCommand( params ));
  } catch ( error ) {
  }
};
```

I've been searching for hours and haven't been able to pinpoint the issue, although I've tried changing values in my `tsconfig.json` file and have tried multiple versions of Node (14.x, 16.x, 18.x), but would like to use 16.15.0.  Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

I've created a sample repo on Github showing the error in action: https://github.com/autoboxer/aws-sdk-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the modules within `@aws-sdk/client-sns/dist-es` are exported from vanilla JS files, which may not be picked up based on how you're configuring module resolution in your webpack config.

Try adding `.js` to your extensions array:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.ts', '.tsx', '.js' ]
}
```

That should allow webpack to resolve the vanilla JS modules within `@aws-sdk/client-sns`, and will hopefully resolve this issue as well.

Comment: That did it, thank you very much @n-devr.